# Basic and strange question involving rules of inference

Tags: logic

Consider the following propositions:

If Mary is not a teacher, Adrian is a student. If Joana is a director, Mary is a teacher. Either Joana is a director, or John is a secretary.
Knowing that John is secretary:
A) Mary is a teacher.
B) Adrian is a student.
C) John  is a teacher.
D) Joana is a director.

I built the argument with the conclusions of the alternatives and, in no case, did I get a tautological conditional. Is this more "technical" approach appropriate for this type of issue?
Another thing that bothers me is the fact that the statement states that John is a secretary and then put it in the alternatives that he is a teacher.

Comment: Are you using the Inclusive Or here?  Though either way I see no way to conclude any of these.  I guess you could conclude that $c$ is false though we are not told that the professions are mutually exclusive so even that seems a stretch.

Comment: I don't think one can conclude anything.  If John, Joanna, and Mary are secretaries, and Marian and Adrian are teachers, then none of the alternatives hold, and all $3$ statement are true, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Do you have the source of this problem? It looks like part of it is missing.

Comment: IF we assume the OR are exclusive (we shouldn't) and that the careers are mutually exclusive (we shouldn't) and if we assume the if then is an if and only if (we *really* shouldn't).  The we can conclude John is secretrary so Joana is not a director so Mary is not a teacher so Adrian is a student.  But we *SHOULDN"T* assume IF means IF AND ONLY IF (it *doesn't*) or that an OR means one or the other (it *doesn't*) or that John can't be *both* a secretary and a teacher (that's a more reasonable assumption but it's still not valid).

Comment: @fleablood +1 Very nicely phrased.  In fact, given the OP's (very legitimate) question, I think that **all of your analysis** should be transplanted into an answer.